# Make a fan rotate constantly throughout the game in BGE

Tags: game-engine

I'm a currently starting to work on a blender game and I'm beginning to worry about the small details.

For example if I had my characters in a room and there was a desk fan on a table, how could I make that fan constantly move throughout the game?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you turn the fan axis via a motion actuator:

[image]

Comment: Oh I see. But how would I make the fan like literally move? Say I create the object, do I need to add a rigid body to it or do something with keyframes?

Comment: What you mean with literally move? The above logic bricks make the object rotate. It does not change position. You can apply this logic to any object.

Comment: What I mean is, I don't want the whole obeject rotating, only the fan itself.

Comment: I suggest to use two objects. The fan and the body. Turn the fan with the method described above.